# Strange "apt-get purge" behaviour with regEx

Tags: apt, regular-expression

I'm running Debian (jessie) and following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24482920/how-can-i-properly-configure-my-eclipse-luna-dark-theme) question, I followed the first answer suggestion to install that packages running

```
sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-* gtk3-engines*
```

That did not resolve my problem with Eclipse btw, but then I noticed something strange: when I ran

```
sudo apt-get purge gtk2-engines-* gtk3-engines*
```

it said

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'gtk2-engines-gartoon' for regex 'gtk2-engines-*'
Note, selecting 'gtk2-engines-moblin' for regex 'gtk2-engines-*'
Note, selecting 'gtk2-engines-murrine' for regex 'gtk2-engines-*'
Note, selecting 'gtk2-engines-nodoka' for regex 'gtk2-engines-*'
Note, selecting 'gtk2-engines-qtcurve' for regex 'gtk2-engines-*'
Note, selecting 'gtk2-engines-ubuntulooks' for regex 'gtk2-engines-*'
Note, selecting 'gtk2-engines-pixbuf' for regex 'gtk2-engines-*'
Note, selecting 'gtk2-engines' for regex 'gtk2-engines-*'
Note, selecting 'gtk2-engines-wonderland' for regex 'gtk2-engines-*'
Note, selecting 'gtk2-engines-oxygen' for regex 'gtk2-engines-*'
Note, selecting 'gtk2-engines-cleanice' for regex 'gtk2-engines-*'
Note, selecting 'gtk2-engines-magicchicken' for regex 'gtk2-engines-*'
Note, selecting 'gtk2-engines-xfce' for regex 'gtk2-engines-*'
Note, selecting 'gtk2-engines-aurora' for regex 'gtk2-engines-*'
Note, selecting 'gnome-icon-theme-gartoon' instead of 'gtk2-engines-gartoon'
Note, selecting 'gtk3-engines-oxygen' for regex 'gtk3-engines*'
Note, selecting 'gtk3-engines-xfce' for regex 'gtk3-engines*'
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  kde-style-qtcurve kwin-style-qtcurve libgoocanvas-common libgoocanvas3
  libkdecorations4abi2 libmlt++3 libmlt-data libmlt6 libsox-fmt-alsa
  libsox-fmt-base libsox2 melt python-httplib2 python-mlt python-pygoocanvas
  python-xdg
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
```

And that was ok, but then it said

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  gtk2-engines* gtk2-engines-aurora* gtk2-engines-cleanice*
  gtk2-engines-magicchicken* gtk2-engines-moblin* gtk2-engines-murrine*
  gtk2-engines-nodoka* gtk2-engines-oxygen* gtk2-engines-pixbuf*
  gtk2-engines-qtcurve* gtk2-engines-ubuntulooks* gtk2-engines-wonderland*
  gtk2-engines-xfce* gtk3-engines-oxygen* gtk3-engines-xfce* murrine-themes*
  openshot* xfce4*
```

Why did he also select

```
murrine-themes* openshot* xfce4*
```

?

Shouldn't it just remove all matching cases of regEx

```
gtk2-engines-* gtk3-engines*
```

or am I missing something basic here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ apt-cache show xfce4 | grep ^Depends
Depends: xfwm4 (>= 4.12.0), xfconf (>= 4.12.0), xfce4-settings (>= 4.12.0), xfce4-panel (>= 4.12.0), xfdesktop4 (>= 4.12.0), thunar (>= 1.6.6), gtk2-engines-xfce (>= 3.2.0), xfce4-session (>= 4.12.0), xfce4-appfinder (>= 4.12.0), xfce4-mixer (>= 4.10.0), orage (>= 4.10.0), libxfce4ui-utils (>= 4.12)
```

As you can see, package xfce4 depends on gtk2-engines-xfce, so if you remove gtk2-engines-xfce, apt will also remove xfce4.
It's similiar with other packages you have mentioned, so openshot depends on gtk2-engines-pixbuf and gtk2-engines-pixbuf depends on gtk2-engines-murrine

I would also like to point to Henrik's comment; 
apt-get can take regex as argument in place of package names, but you have to take care of file globbing that takes place before shell actually calls command. Look at the example:

```
$ touch gtk2-engine-test
$ sudo apt-get remove gtk2-engine*
[sudo] password for boban: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gtk2-engine-test
```

When you want to pass regex to apt, you should escape file globbing characters like *,?,[,] and so on, so correct command would be:

```
sudo apt-get remove gtk2-engine\*
```

Comment: (Technically it isn't regexps but globs) It looks like gtk2-engines-xfce was already installed before you did the install.

Answer (score 2):

As already [explained by Boban P.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/271030/strange-apt-get-purge-behaviour-with-regex/271032#271032), if you request to remove or purge a package, that will also remove packages that depend on it.

You can use `aptitude why` to see what manually installed packages depend on a package, i.e. why the package is installed. The argument is a single package name¹, not a glob pattern or a regexp. You can combine it with an [aptitude search]((http://aptitude.alioth.debian.org/doc/en/ch02s04s05.html) to query multiple packages at once.

```
aptitude -v why $(aptitude -F %p search '~i ~ngtk2-engines.*')
```

Beware that the output can be very long. Without `-v`, aptitude only lists a single reason why each package is installed.

Additionally, note that the argument of `apt-get` and `apt-cache` commands is a regular expression, not a shell wildcard pattern. If the argument doesn't contain any special character, it's used literally, but if the argument does contain special characters `()[].?*+` then the regexp only needs to match a part of the package name. So `gtk2-engines-*` matches the packages that have `gtk2-engines` as a substring²; that's why `gtk2-engines` was listed as matched. You probably meant to write `gtk2-engines-.*` instead, but this would also have caught packages whose name doesn't start with `gtk2-engines`³. To list packages that start with `gtk2-engines-`, use `^gtk2-engines-`.

Also, get into the habit of quoting special characters in a shell command line — if there had been a file matching the glob pattern `gtk2-engines-*` in the current directory (e.g. a `.deb` file that you'd just downloaded) then the pattern would have been replaced by the matching file(s).

¹  <sub>Or an [aptitude search pattern](http://aptitude.alioth.debian.org/doc/en/ch02s04s05.html) in some versions, but not on Debian jessie.</sub> 
²  <sub>Because `gtk2-engines` ends with zero or more occurrences of `-` (namely zero).</sub> 
³  <sub>Of which there aren't any in Debian at the moment.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I thought that `purge` and `remove` only affected _sub-packages_ that depended on those _main packages_ **and were not requested from other packages**. So, assume that I installed _package1_ which required _package2_ and _package3_ (with _package3_ already installed because required from another package), is there a way to remove **just _package1_ and _package2_** without removing _package3_?

Comment: @igng Assuming that package2 wasn't installed explicitly, `apt-get remove package1` followed by `apt-get autoremove`. If you explicitly call `remove` or `purge`, that means “do whatever it takes to get this package off my machine”.